# Matplotlib twin axis label drawn in bad position after cla() method

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

using the following code I get the correct result with the twin axis label in the correct position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

figure, ax = plt.subplots()
twin1 = ax.twinx()
 
ax.set_ylabel("axis1")
twin1.set_ylabel("axis2")

"""
ax.cla()
twin1.cla()

ax.set_ylabel("axis1")
twin1.set_ylabel("axis2")
"""

plt.show()
```

however if I uncomment the code with the cla() methods, the twin axis label is not returned to the correct position. Why?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved. It seems the cla() method resets the label position property to "left", which apparently is set to "right" when the twin axis is created. So I added the following line before plt.show():

```
twin1.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
```